# Missing attributes when importing Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook

I 'm trying to add the facebook-android-sdk dependency within an Android project. First I added this to build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.36.1'
```

So the app/build.gradle looked like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.enricolobianco.test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.36.1'
}
```

When building, it gave me this error:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 28.0.0, 27.0.2. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and
>   com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2 less... (Ctrl+F1)  There are
>   some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are
>   incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is
>   compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not
>   the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your
>   targetSdkVersion).

[image: error]

To solve that, I changed from this:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.36.1'
```

to this:

```
implementation ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.36.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'cardview-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'customtabs'
}
```

But this error popped out:

[image: second error]

And I don't know how to solve this one. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'

Just use above version which Facebook is using. Do not change fb sdk dependency.

Comment: That does work but forces me to use sdk version 27 as compileSdkVersion and therefore targetSdkVersion. I'll accept this solution as I don't require sdkVersion to be 28. Thanks for your help.